# 1000 doors, few keys as possible problem

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I haven't dealt with college level math in a little while, so forgive me if this is a little trivial.  It feels like it has something to do with the birthday paradox...but the opposite.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Starter question:

If you have 1000 doors, and 1 key, how many doors would you have to open, until you had over a 95% expectancy that your one key will open all 1000 doors.

Next question:

If you have 1000 doors, and 2 keys, how many doors would you have to open, until you had over a 95% expectancy that your two keys will open all 1000 doors.

Final question:

If you have 1000 doors, and $n$ keys, how many doors would you have to open, until you had over a 95% expectancy that your $n$ keys will open all 1000 doors.

For all, these are given:

- $D$ is the set of doors.
- $K$ is the set of keys.
- $|K| \le |D|$
- Keys and doors do not wear out.  Physical attributes don't matter
- Each door opening is independent of other door openings
- We want to know if any key in set $K$ will open $D_i$ where $0 < i \le |D|$
- Doors are opened at random

Comment: I would say the answer to each is $1000$. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: You won't know for certain unless you know for sure!

Comment: I think we need a little more information. Does each key open the same number of doors? Does each key have to open any door at all?

Comment: OK.  I guess that having a 99.9% possibility would work well enough.  If you think about the birthday paradox, if there are 23 people in a room, the chances of two people sharing a birthday is 50%.  I think that there's a similar issue here.  We're taking a discrete random variable, and testing m doors, until we have confidence that we've covered enough doors.

Comment: you choose the doors randomly? and also the key when there are several?

Comment: @FrankMcGovern, the keys can open up any number of doors.  Each key can open a minimum of 0 doors.  ;)

Comment: @wece, if you're at a door, you can try any of your n keys.  Each door can be opened by, at most, 1 key.

Comment: Then same remark as Gerry, why its not 1000? (or 999 for 99,9%). I don't get it.

Comment: I'm not talking about probability.  I'm thinking of expectancy.  Example: If you're sitting on your porch, and you watch cars drive by, each time a non-red car drives past, the expectancy of the next car being red increases every time a non-red car passes by.  The probability will always remain the same.  Expectancy varies based off of previous data.

Comment: Thinking about it further, I think that I could use the probability.  If you want to be certain that two people in the same room have the same birthday, why wouldn't you just put 367 people in the room?  Well, doing some math, we see that putting 60 people in the room gives you a probability that there's a 99.4122660865348% chance that 2 people have the same birthday.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: @achillehui: while useful in a physical problem, adding concerns not addressed in a math question is usually not helpful. Math problems are often idealized so that they can be solved.

Comment: @onelife Yes, it makes sense that you can just use the notion of probability.  Probability (or conditional probability) suffices to formalize most informal notions of "expectancy".  Mathematically speaking, 99.4122660865348% is not equal to 100%, so if you just want the probability to be _close_ to 100% then you should revise the question to reflect this (including a definition of "close".)

Comment: @TrevorWilson, edited.  Thanks.

Comment: In fact I don't see the link with the birthday paradox. Each people are given one birthday randomly over 365 days. What about your keys?

Comment: If you went into it with a prior expectation, you could use Bayes' Theorem to update your expectation, and calculate quite easily when it exceeds 95 percent. The tricky part is the prior expectation, that is, before you try any doors, how do you assign a probability to the event of your key(s) opening all the doors?

Comment: In addition to what Gerry said, you would also need to incorporate some assumption about whether the event of the key opening door 1 is correlated with the event of the key opening lock 2, _etc._

Comment: All of the door/key combinations are independent of one another.  I'm trying to figure out what @GerryMyerson pointed out, with the initial probability.  If we're just approaching it without prior knowledge, I would guess that it would be 1/n where n would be number of doors.

Comment: Ok, some questions are left in your edit.

"Each door opening is independent of other door openings" But what is the probability that a key, say $k_i$, open a door say $d_j$?
What do you mean by "Doors are opened at random"? That you choose randomly a door and try to open it with all your keys? For example that you tries the doors $d_1,d_6,d_4,d_1,d_1,\dots$?

Comment: I said that doors are opened at random, so that no one worries about the physical attributes of the locks.  I'll clean up the question, to answer your question.  I guess with each door opening, the chance that $K_j$ opens door $D_i$, is $1/(|K|*|D|)$.

Answer (score 1):

From my real-world experience, I would say if it opens more than 100 doors it is intended to open all the doors.  Of course, one lock might be broken.

If you are trying to distinguish between a key that opens 999 doors and one that opens 1000, once you have opened 999 doors you have eliminated the first at a 99.9% level.  Once you have opened 990 you have eliminated the first at a 99% level.  What level of certainty do you want?  If you want 100%, you need to try them all.

If you have more than one key, you need to define the protocol more carefully.  Do you try the first, if that fails try the second, but if the first does work you don't try the second?  I think then the number of keys doesn't matter-you can consider one "union" key that opens all the doors that at least one of your set opens.  If you try them all in each door, and they all work every time you get more information.

Comment: You are correct, with the assumption that I don't care which key opens the door (the union of keys).  Just that one key works in each door.  My issue now, is that I'm a programmer.  I need to write something that takes a really long time to run, and optimize it as much as possible.  If there's a 5% miss rate, that's very acceptable.  If I could get a formula, to estimate how many cycles that I need to run (or doors that I need to open), then I think that I might be able to get something more specific than 10%.  (Although my solution for tomorrow will probably be 10%...)

Answer (score 0):

For one key, if you denote $O_k$ the event that your key opened the first $k$ doors. What you want is the smallest $k$ such that $P(O_{1000}|O_k)>0.95$ right?
$$P(O_{1000}|O_k)=\frac{P(o_k|O_{1000})P(O_{1000})}{P(O_k)}=\frac{1*\left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{1000} }{\left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{k}}=\left(\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{1000-k}$$
this gives you $k>999$.

Is that what you want?

Comment: I still have to do the math, but I don't understand the answer.  You're saying that I'd need 999 keys to open 950 doors.  Right there, you'd have a spare 49 keys.

Comment: Ok, this may not be what you wanted then. This say that you need to be sure to open 1000 with one key to have a probability greater than 0.95 to open 1000 door with one key. This is due to that fact that even if you opened the 999 first one you only have $1/1000$ chance to open the last one ...

Comment: Gotcha.  If $K$ represents the set of all keys, and $D$ represents the set of all doors, the $|D| \le |K|$.  I feel like that I need to update the question, to better reflect all of these restraints that you folks have given me.

Comment: You seem to be implicitly assuming that $P(O_1)=1/1000$.  Where did you get that assumption from?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen from his last comment: "I guess with each door opening, the chance that $K_j$ opens door $D_i$, is $\frac{1}{(|K|∗|D|)}=1/1000$ for one key and 1000 of doors.